# Estou com problemas para juntar 2 matrizes

Tags: python

```
def matrizsomada(a, b):

    num_elementos_a = len(a)
    num_elementos_b = len(b)

    x = []

    for i in range(num_elementos_a or num_elementos_b):
       x.append([a[i],b[i]])

    return x

a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']

print(matrizsomada(a,b))
```

- Quero que retorne a saída como [1,'a',2,'b',3,'c','d','e'] ,mas está dando o erro

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Answer (score 2):

Seu iterador deve percorrer pela lista de maior tamanho. Crie também duas proteções de índices que permitam adicionar em `x` somente elementos de `a` e de `b` cujo o índice `i` seja individualmente valido:

```
def matrizsomada(a, b):    
    x = []
    lenA = len(a)
    lenB = len(b)
    # a função max(lenA,lenB) retornará o maior valor entre lenA e lenB
    for i in range(max(lenA,lenB)): 
      if i < lenA: x.append(a[i]) # Só adiciona se índice i for menor que o comprimento de a 
      if i < lenB: x.append(b[i]) # Só adiciona se índice i for menor que o comprimento de b

    return x

a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']

print(matrizsomada(a,b))
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/PlumpAdvancedFields

Comment: Muito obrigado! Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil considere aceita-lá.

Comment: Leia [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)